# Node.js update db object on save event in another

Tags: node.js, events, mongoose

What is the most convenient way to create/update object on saving changes to other? Imagine we have a model Client and we emit event on save.

```
clientSchema.post('save', function (client) {
    process.emit('clientUpdate', client);
});
```

Then we can subscribe for that event like:

```
process.on('clientUpdate', function(client) {
  //LOGIC GOES HERE
});
```

Let's assume we want now to update ClientProjection. Where you would locate the listener and how you would implement update logic for mongoDB(mongoose)- using model, by dao, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can avoid emitting another event and just make the update within the post-save hook. For example:

```
clientSchema.post('save', function (client, next) {
    ClientProjection.update( {/*  Query Parameters */}, 
                             {/* Data to update */}, 
                             function(err, clientProjection) {
                                 next()
                             }
});
```

In a post-save hook, if you want to call an async function, you'll need to add `next` as your second argument and invoke it in the callback when the async action is complete. See the `Asynchronous Post Hooks` section of the [mongoose Middleware docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: It looks nice but there are more than one post-save hook to update ClientProjection so it would be nice to aggregate update logic in one place. That is why I prefer events. Although I found some trouble with this as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888777/scope-of-events-from-process-emit-in-node-js. maybe you can help me with this?