# Scope of events from process.emit in Node.js

Tags: node.js, events, scope

I have code to sent event like this:

```
process.emit('event', event);
```

I would like to listen to these event like this:

```
process.on('event', function(event) {
     //HANDLING LOGIC
});
```

It works fine when files are located in the same folder. When I located listener in other folder it is not fired. 
What can be a root cause of this and hwo can I handle it?

**EDIT:**

The actual problem was just a missing expose with a file including event handling. Shame on me.

Comment: How are you loading those files?

Comment: @robertklep Not sure what you mean? I thought (maybe incorrectly) that whenever I use process I also load events module which has global scope in terms of distributing events. I checked this also with my own file which exposes implicitly the eventEmitter but it also doesn't work.

Comment: You write, _"when I located listener in other folder"_, which implies that you are loading the file that contains that listener somehow. To be clear: event emitters only work within the same (Node) process, you can't emit in one process and receive those events in another process.

Comment: @robertklep Your questions helped me to solve the actual issue, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `process` is a single global instance. the scope should not be related to your problem.

[process in node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have initialised the eventListener before emiting event.

Comment: This answer could be a comment